# Back button not working after input / search submit

Tags: forms, input, autocomplete

Thanks to [Sally CJ](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/137402/sally-cj) I am super close to having everything figured out with an autocomplete search I am building out. The only problem I am having is the back button is not working after the user is taken to their new page (based on what they chose from the dropdown / autocomplete box). Sometimes the back button is simply greyed out and other times it will take the user to what seems like a random page (or whatever page they visited 2-3 pages prior).

Below is my full code, any suggestions for a fix would be greatly appreciated. I'm guessing it has something to do with `window.location.replace(permalink)` but not completely sure.

```
 /**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts.
 */
function theme_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Enqueue jQuery UI and autocomplete
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-autocomplete' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_scripts' );

/**
 * Enqueue ui styles
 */
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    // Enqueue jQuery UI themed styles.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-redmond-core', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css', array(), null );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-redmond-theme', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css', array(), null );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' ); 

/**
 * Add a shortcode for autocomplete drop down
 *
 * Use: [autocomplete]
 */
function theme_autocomplete_dropdown_shortcode( $atts ) {
    return '<input type="text" name="autocomplete" id="autocomplete" value="" placeholder="start typing artist name..." />';
}
add_shortcode( 'autocomplete', 'theme_autocomplete_dropdown_shortcode' );

function theme_autocomplete_js() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'show',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_key'  => 'deal_date',
        'posts_per_page'   => -1 // all posts
    );

    $posts = get_posts( $args );

        if( $posts ) :
            foreach( $posts as $k => $post ) {
                $source[$k]['ID'] = $post->ID;                                      
                $source[$k]['label'] = $post->post_title ." - ".  get_field('deal_date', $post->ID);        
                $source[$k]['permalink'] = get_permalink( $post->ID );
                $source[$k]['value'] = '';
            }

    ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            var posts = <?php echo json_encode( array_values( $source ) ); ?>;

            jQuery( 'input[name="autocomplete"]' ).autocomplete({
                source: posts,
                minLength: 2,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    var permalink = ui.item.permalink; // Get permalink from the datasource
                    window.location.replace(permalink);                     
                }
            });
        });  

    </script> 

    <?php
    endif;
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'theme_autocomplete_js' );
```

Answer (score 0):

simple fix, changed to: `window.location.href = (permalink);`